# How to show progress during an IO operation

Tags: java, file-io, progress

I want to read elements from array and display progress of reading as parallel process reading.

I have two interal classes:

```
public class NumbersCounter {

    int totalCountOfLines;
    int currentCountOfLines = 1;

    public NumbersCounter() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {    
        new Read();
        new Progress();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new NumbersCounter();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NumbersCounter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NumbersCounter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    class Progress extends Thread {  
        public Progress() {
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {        
            synchronized(new Object()) {
                while (currentCountOfLines <= totalCountOfLines) {
                    System.out.println(currentCountOfLines / totalCountOfLines * 100 + "%");
                    Thread.yield();
                }            
            }
    }}

    class Read extends Thread {
        private FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("ololo.txt");
        private String[] lines;

        public Read() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            this.lines = fh.readFromFile();
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            totalCountOfLines = this.lines.length;

            if (totalCountOfLines > 0) {
                synchronized(new Object()) {
                    for (String line : lines) {
                        currentCountOfLines++;   
                        Thread.yield();
                    }

                }
            } else {
                totalCountOfLines = 0;
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

When first step of Read Thread is executed, I need to give executing to Progress thread, and then for Read, and then for Progress.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream` class for a wrapper for your input stream, that displays a dialog of the progress.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation on java.util.concurrent package.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Specifically the ExecutorService, Executor, Callable and Future interfaces.  The concurrent package is built to do what your trying to do without you having to deal with locking and concurrency on your own.

IO operation in the background - progressively update the UI.